# postgres multiple JDBC select statements in batch

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, jdbc, batch-processing

How do you issue a single JDBC call to Postgres which includes 2 select statements? The two select statements select from different sets of tables and return two different result sets - so cannot be union-ed. The goal is to ensure that what is read from the database is a consistent snapshot of data in the tables at the instant the selects are issues. If two separate select statements are issued, there is a chance of some data getting updated after the first select and before the second one.

Look like java.sql.Statement's addBatch() and executeBatch() can not be used - this can only be used for updates. Attempting to use it with selects causes a PSQLException with message "A result was returned when none was expected." on executeBatch().

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to jump through any hoops for this. Just `BEGIN` a transaction in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation and the two statements will see a consistent view of the data.

See [the JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

There is no other way to ensure two statements see the same data. You could send them together, but unless they're wrapped in a transaction they could still see different data.